# Conda cloning an environment to a wrong target directory

Tags: anaconda, conda

Currently my conda environments are in /opt/anaconda3/envs. I have multiple users in my desktop server and the /opt/anaconda3/ is the system-wide conda directory for all users.
When I clone an environment from there, it makes a new target directory in my local directory

```
/home/my_username/.conda/envs/cloned_env
```

And it persists (creates again when I attempt cloning after deleting it) even when I erase .conda folder in my local home directory.
I tried to set conda environment location by editing .condarc file in my local home directory (added following)

```
envs_dirs:
    - /opt/anaconda3/envs
```

However, it still doesn't work.
Although it seems I can still use the cloned environment, I want to make the cloned environment in the systemwide conda directory /opt/anaconda3/envs so that other users can use it. What am I missing here?